# OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348:

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

**I'm new to docker and trying to run an app. When I run the following command**

```
docker-compose run --rm flaskapp /bin/bash -c "cd /opt/services/flaskapp/src && python -c  'import database; database
.init_db()'"
```

**I get the below error**

```
Starting systemspuzzlemaster_db_1 ... done
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: 
container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: 
\"C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/bash\": stat C:/Program 
Files/Git/usr/bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown
```

**Can someone help me what am I doing wrong?**
Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir -p /opt/services/flaskapp/src
COPY requirements.txt /opt/services/flaskapp/src/
WORKDIR /opt/services/flaskapp/src
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /opt/services/flaskapp/src
EXPOSE 5001

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Comment: What is in your docker-compose.yml file?